# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported (IE only)

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsp, http, spring-mvc

When I submit the JSP form, I get `405 - Request method 'POST' not supported` error message in IE.

The same application works fine in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but throws error message in IE 6,7 and 8

My JSP:

```
<form:form name="create" action="submit.view" method="POST" commandName="xxx">
    ....
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class TicketController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/submit.view", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submit(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @ModelAttribute("xxx") Form TicketForm, BindingResult result)
            throws Exception {
            ...
            ...
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why I get these error messages only in IE?

Comment: Only in IE? This contradicts the nature of the error you got. Please track HTTP requests with Fiddler2 and check for differences in every browser (particularly the request URI and raw headers). Include the observations in your question. All I can think of is that IE is been configured to use a proxy which in turn is broken.

Comment: if it is showing HTTP error then it should be same in all browsers. Get or Post method doesm't depend on Browser. May be you are missing something else.

Comment: We ran across this issue in IE when we were submitting a single item in the form.  It only happened when we had a form with one element, and the enter button was used to submit the form.  We solved by adding a blank field to the form or by further limiting the scope of the params required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast worked. The problem arised was in security. We had used NTLM, but when we changed to LDAP the issue got resolved. Not sure why NTLM didnt work. But issue got resolved

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "*/submit.view", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Maybe IE change form action url